# Second counter on Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

I am trying to show a seconds counter in my beamer presentation.
I came up with this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{madrid}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \foreach \t in {0,1,...,9} {
        \begin{frame}
            \transduration{1}
            \frametitle{Personal information}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Jordi Altayó González
                \item Born on July 28, 1996
                \item Sabadell
            \end{itemize}   
            \vfill
            \begin{flushright}
                \t
            \end{flushright}                
        \end{frame}
    }
\end{document}
```

The problem is that slide numbers get messed up.
Is there any way I can show this counter without changing frame every time it gets updated?

### @samcarter answer

The problem with this answer is that now the counter shifts right on every slide:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may be better off using overlays instead of making a new frame with each iteration:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \transduration{1}
    \frametitle{Personal information}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Jordi Altayó González
        \item Born on July 28, 1996
        \item Sabadell
    \end{itemize}   
    \vfill
    \foreach \t in {0,1,...,9} {%
        \only<+>{%
            \begin{flushright}
                \t
            \end{flushright}
        }%
    }%             
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. The only problem with your solution is that the counter seems to shift right on every slide (I'll edit my answer to show it)

Comment: @jagjordi please see my edited answer